# Add Pintrest and Google+ to RWD

Tags: social-buttons

So i want to add the pintrest and G+ icon to the RWD package on the , i am guessing it will involve adding some code to sharing.phtml in the rwd directory? and something in the skin as well as the style sheet. I know my way around magento but could use some help. As i said I am looking for very detailed instructions to accomplish this task.  Thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple. In rwd theme.

**Step 1:** Open this folder `app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog\product\view`.

**Step 2:** Find `sharing.phtml` file.

**Step 3:**  Add new `li` tag at last as below.

```
<li>
   <a href="//www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=<?php echo $_productUrl;?>" data-pin-do="buttonPin" data-pin-shape="round" target="_blank" title="<?php echo $this->__('Share on pinterest') ?>"><img src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pinit_fg_en_round_red_16.png" /></a>
</li>
```

**Ste 4:** At last `Please call pinit.js only once per page`

```
<script type="text/javascript" async src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

**Step 5:** Now for `Google Plus`.

```
<!-- Place this tag where you want the share button to render. -->
<div class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-annotation="none" data-height="15" data-href="<?php echo $_productUrl;?>"></div>
```

**Step 6:**  Please add below code.

```
<!-- Place this tag in your head or just before your close body tag. -->
<li>
   <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>                   
</li>
```

Step 7:** Save file refresh cache.

Let me know if any comments.

**Note::** If Button is not display Proper then we have to set CSS by Own.

Comment: I will update google + by tomorrow morning

Comment: So I am not sure if this matters these will be on only product pages and i put the JS scripts in the Miscellaneous Scripts head section in the admin? i am confused as to why you have the <li> for the js script too. so it looks as though i need to set the css as the buttons are touching just need some padding i think please advise, i am learning still , i have to ask. Thanks in advance

Comment: U can do one thing add js file on only in product detail page don't add in li tag.

Comment: You can do one thing just add two button on site share link with us I will then give suggestion for csss